# How do you open the Expression Editor Dialog from a Custom Activity Designer in a Rehosted Windows Workflow 4 Designer?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I would like to add a button to our custom activity designers, to allow users the ability open the Expression Editor dialog.
I would like the same behavior as clicking the ellipse button that appears in the Property Grid.

Just so you are aware, we implemented an IExpressionEditorInstance and IExpressionEditorService and registered them with the Workflow Designer.
The custom Expression Editor works great in the property grid, on the design surface, and in the built in Expression Editor Dialog.

The following code almost works.

When I click the button on the custom activity dialog, the custom Expression Editor Dialog appears.
I can see the VB expression in an Instance of IExpressionEditorInstance (with syntax highlighting and intellisense).
I can make a change, and click OK.

Sadly, when I tab to the OK button, the IExpressionEditorInstance looses focus and switches back to a readonly Textbox. (The built-in editor does not do that.)
Also, I found that if I tab back and forth between the IExpressionEditorInstance and the OK button, the Expression switches between edited version and original version.

I am wondering if there is an easier way of doing this, that I may have missed.
Or any guidance on how to implement the same behavior as the built in Expression Editor Dialog.

Here is what I have so far:

1)  I added a button to my custom activity designer.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=EnvokeExpressionEditorCommand}">...</Button>
```

2)  The Command does the following:

```
private void DoEnvokeMessageExpressionEditorCommand()
    {
        ExpressionEditorDialog dialog = new ExpressionEditorDialog(this.ModelItem, "MyProperty");
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

3)  The ExpressionEidtoryDialog looks like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.ExpressionEditor.ExpressionEditorDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
        xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.ExpressionEditor"
        Title="Expression Editor" Height="150" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>        
            <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" x:Uid="swdv:ArgumentToExpressionConverter_1" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="OK" Click="btn_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="6" Width="70" />        
        <sapv:ExpressionTextBox x:Name="etb" x:Uid="PART_expressionTextBox"  Margin="6" Focusable="True" />        
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

4)  The code behind look like the following.

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Model;
using System.Activities.Presentation.View;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyApp.ExpressionEditor
{
    public partial class ExpressionEditorDialog : Window
    {
        ModelProperty condition;
        ModelItem root;

        public ExpressionEditorDialog(ModelItem item, string propertyName)
        {            
            root = item;
            condition = item.Properties[propertyName];

            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += ExpressionEditorDialog_Loaded;

        }

        public ModelItem ConditionValue
        {
            get
            {
                return condition.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                condition.SetValue(value);
            }
        }

        private void ExpressionEditorDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btn.Command = DesignerView.CommitCommand;  
            btn.CommandTarget = etb;

            etb.OwnerActivity = root;
            etb.ExpressionType = typeof(string);
            etb.HintText = "Enter a VB Expression";
            etb.ExplicitCommit = false;            

            Binding binding = new Binding("Condition");
            binding.Source = this;
            binding.ConverterParameter = ArgumentDirection.In;
            binding.Converter = new ArgumentToExpressionConverter();
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ConditionValue");
            etb.SetBinding(ExpressionTextBox.ExpressionProperty, binding);

            etb.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnExpressionTextBoxLoaded);

        }

        void OnExpressionTextBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            (sender as ExpressionTextBox).BeginEdit();
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = true;
            DesignerView.CommitCommand.Execute(etb);            
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you already try to decompile Microsoft.Activities.Design.dll? Have fun! :D